# Calling a inner div inside a component - React Js

Tags: reactjs

**Component Code:**

```
Class Section extends Component{
   render(){
      return(<div>
              <div className="section">
                <div className="content">
                </div>
               </div>
             </div>  
     )
  }

}
```

**App.js Code**

```
Class App extends Component{
      render(){
        return(
       <Section></Section>
    <!-- here i need to call the inner or child div which is **content** from the component how can i call that one here -->

   )

  }

}
```

I need to call the content div multiple times how can i call that one

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by calling the content div

Comment: i can call <Section></Section>
               <Section></Section> like these for multiple times so it will be rendered , is there any method so i can call the inner div of section like this <Content></Content>
       <Content></Content> for multiple times

Comment: Why don't you write a new `Content` component for that?

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this solve your purpose?

**Content.js**

```
Class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        {this.props.content}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Section.js**

```
Class Section extends Component{
   render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <div className="section">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
       </div>  
     )
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
Class App extends Component{
      render(){
        return(
       <Section>
         <Content content="HELLO WORLD!" />
         <Content content="HELLO UNIVERSE!" />
       </Section>           
   )
  }
}
```